# Get the non-hover css backgroundColor prop of an element currently being hovered over

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I've got a table of rows which "expand" when clicked (by inserting a new row after the clicked row) and I'm using css to zebra-style the cells in the rows as well as a 'highlighting' style for cells when a row is hovered over.

I want the inserted row to have the same background color of the row that was clicked.

I'm trying to set the backgroundColor of cells of inserted rows with jQuery using the backgroundColor property of the first cell in the clicked row.

When I do this, however, I get the 'highlighting' colour because I'm hovered over the clicked row - I want the non-hover value.

css:

```
.zebra-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.zebra-striped tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

jQuery:

```
table.find('tbody').find('tr').on('click',function() {
    var colourOfRow = $(this).find("td").filter(":first").css('backgroundColor');
    var newRows = $('<tr><td style="background-color:'+colourOfRow+';" colspan="'+numCols+'" rowspan="2">Fetching comment...</td></tr><tr></tr>');
    newRows.insertAfter($(this));
});
```

I'm sure I can solve this by storing the colour before I need to use it, but my question is:

Is there a jQuery selector that I've missed or some other well known trick?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. Don't.

The better way to update colors/styles is to add/remove classes. Define your styles in CSS and then add/remove the classes to make the display confirm.

Trying to toggle states by comparing the information in jQuery is wacky!

Comment: Zebra-striping a table is done simply by adding the `.zebra-striped` to the `table` elem and I would like to avoid messing with that simplicity.  Would you mind expanding your answer to include reasons why I shouldn't do what I want to do?

Comment: Wait; you don't actually care what the color is, right? The color is based on whether the index is even or odd, so just grab the index. What are you going to do with the background color anyway? The reason you don't do it by comparing the color data is for exactly this reason; it's very complicated to get and compare css properties of elements and much easier to just apply predefined states/styles to the elements.

Comment: Either that, or move the base color to the TR and just change the TD color on highlight (unless your margins prevent that from working); that way the TR color never changes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take the background color of the same cell of the +2 or -2 row? If there's only one row you can add more rows get the color and delete them quickly.
I think that the best way is to save colors for odd and even elements and use them later when needed. 
But then again (I'm not sure is this the case) If you can add a row after clicking a row that has already been added gives you another problem :)

Comment: Yours is a fair solution @szym.  It means some extra dom manipulation if there aren't +-2 rows (which is something I try to avoid for performance reasons) - although, the impact is likely to be much less in that case than if there were many rows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm solving it for the moment (and thanks to @Mathletics and @szym for their answers):

```
tableRows.each(function(index){
    $(this).data('oc', $(this).find("td").filter(":first").css('backgroundColor'));
});
```

and then when I need that colour when in row context:

```
var colourOfRow = $(this).data('oc');
```

probably not the most performant solution, but good enough I think.

I'll leave this question open for a bit just in case someone has a brilliant idea.